# Notepad++ is not showing the error

Tags: notepad++

I have installed notepad++, but when I code wrong so it cannot show the red line or error.
what is the problem in it??

And when I am trying to run the program it cant run,
what's the reason??

Comment: Can you show the code that you think should be red in Notepad++?

Comment: What language are you using? Do you have syntax highlighting turned on? How are you trying to run the program? How does it fail to run? Please add some of these needed details to your question.

Comment: What program are you trying to run? If Notepad++ fails to run, how do you know about the issue with highlighting?

Comment: I am using c++,
how can I on the syntax highlighter??
I am trying to run the program with F5 key,
but it cant run, it shows the notepad++ location folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wondering why it's not showing coding errors, Notepad++ is a text editor, not an IDE. It's not designed to show errors as you type. If you want such a thing, try an IDE such as [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: So which purpose it is use??

Comment: It is purely for editing code. The highlighting will help but other than that it is down to you to know what you're doing.

Comment: There is any function of highlighting in notepad++??

Comment: Highlighting code makes it easier to read.

Comment: Syntax highlighting should be on automatically if you use the correct file extension. If it's not for some reason, it's in the language menu.